# Does Jackrabbit support the XPath union (|) operator?

Tags: xpath, jackrabbit

I am trying to search under 2 different nodes for a specific name. This works

```
/jcr:root/db067409/libraries/bd0b868d/_x0030_//*[@name="FIRST"]
```

But when I try to OR it with the second node like so...

```
/jcr:root/db067409/libraries/bd0b868d/_x0030_//*[@name="FIRST"]|/jcr:root/db067409/libraries/_x0033_78d57e4/_x0031_//*[@name="FIRST"]
```

I no longer get any search results. Please could someone point out what I've done wrong.

What I'd really like to do is along these lines; if I have /a/b/ID1/VERSION1 and /a/b/ID2/VERSION2 I'd like an xpath something like this /a/b/(ID1/VERSION1 or ID2/VERSION2)//*[@name="some name"].

Comment: Just for reference, this is actually a *union*, not an or (which xpath also has).

Comment: I would say yes, yes it is a union. Although, if its easier to just return the first match that would also be of use.

Comment: I've found a few posts, all very old, that says not only does jackrabbit not support union but it also just ignores is instead of throwing an exception :( So I guess the question is, does latest Jackrabbit even support union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is no. Unfortunately, it doesnt throw an UnsupportedOperationException like you'd expect. There was an item in Jira but I guess they ignored it as Xpath is now deprecated.

Use JCR_SQL2 if you do need a union.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

[This thread](http://dev.day.com/discussion-groups/content/lists/cq-google/2010-06/2010-06-24__day_communique_XPath_union_operator_Jacopo_Franzoi.html) indicates that a union-like feature is available in Jackrabbit 2.0, but not earlier.

> [Joins] are not possible with JCR
>   Xpath or JCR-SQL, but with the new query model in JCR 2.0 (JCR-SQL2).
>   This is supported since CQ 5.3 / CRX 2.0 / Jackrabbit 2.0. Please note
>   that these joins aren't optimized very much.

Indeed, [XPath is deprecated in JCR 2.0](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/6_Query.html).

> JCR 1.0 defines a dialect of SQL different from JCR-SQL2, as well as a dialect of XPath. Support for these languages is deprecated.

Comment: I think you've misread that thread. It say its not possible with XPath, but is available in JCR 2.0 using JCR-SQL2.

Comment: And I knew that XPath is deprecated, really.  Pre-senior moment.